# SequelizeJS Order by renamed attribute

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I came across an exception, cannot find solution anywhere. It looks like a bug of sequelizeJs.

Here is the question:

I have two model

```
module.exports = db.sequelize.define('user', {
  // id is added automatically
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'created_at'
  }
})

module.exports = db.sequelize.define('question', {
  // id is added automatically
  userId: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    field: 'user_id'
  }
})

User.hasMany(Question,{foreignKey:'userId',as:'questions'})
```

then I have a query:

```
  models.User.findAll({
      limit:limit,
      order:[['createdAt','DESC']],
      include : [{
      {
        model:models.Question,
        as:"questions"
      },]
    })
```

I got an exception saying: "SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'user.created_at' in 'order clause'"

Here is the generated sql code:

SELECT ***** FROM (SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`created_at` AS `createdAt` FROM `user` AS `user` **ORDER BY `user`.`created_at`** DESC LIMIT 10) AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN `question` AS `questions` ON `user`.`id` = `questions`.`user_id` **ORDER BY `user`.`created_at`** DESC

It seems that order by is applied twice. At the second time, the 'created_at' has been renamed as 'createdAt'. That's why db complains 'cannot find user.created_at'.

My question is how to fix this problem so that I can run my query. I cannot find any available solution. And why Sequelize apply 'order by' twice? it looks like unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue it seems

[See GitHub](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8275)

However, you could try explicitly stating the attributes you want to query for on both models.

Comment: could you explain how to do that? Even I explicitly stating the attributes, it doesn't change anything right? all the field still would be renamed as the Model attribute which means create_at would also be renamed as createdAt.  'Order by user.created_at' would still give the exception : "Unknown column 'question.created_at' in 'order clause'"

Comment: The key point is why order by is applied twice in the generated sql. The second one is obviously unnecessary. If we can remove the "order by" outside, the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no issue with sequelize ,**

Issue in below code : there one extra `{` inside the include block , remove that first

```
models.User.findAll({
    limit:limit,
    order:[['createdAt','DESC']],
    include : [{
    {
        model:models.Question,
        as:"questions"
    },]
})
```

**Query is 100% correct**, I have executed the same way and its working fine from both side (sequelize and sql).

**Issue you may have is :**

1. your user table must have `createdAt` field named `created_at`
2. inside `models.User.findAll()` you might have used `attributes` and
   forgot to add `created_at`

> Try to run query inside your sql, and check for the error

`SELECT ***** 
FROM (SELECT user.id, user.created_at AS createdAt FROM user AS user ORDER BY user.created_at DESC LIMIT 10) 
        AS user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN question AS questions ON user.id = questions.user_id 
ORDER BY user.created_at DESC`

And you will figure it out whats wrong with the query

Comment: yes, the "{" is not needed.  but it still doesn't work for me, could you post your code, pls?

Comment: Code is same as yours , please provide the full model code and also the sequlize query without any code removal.

Comment: @DennisHuang, please hit the sql query directly into your db and post the error , that will be very helpfull.